# HTTP Logstat: Profile Creation for Sitecore Website

Tags: logging, report, sitecore

I want to make a report / analysis of a Sitecore website, but I have problems creating a profile for the website.

This is the profile creation screen:
[image]

What do I put into the "Index Page" field? A Sitecore website doesn't have an index.html or .php.

Then there's the "Path / file mask" field:

[image]

What is the meaning of it? What goes into this field?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

1) Index page equals to main page of your website.
2) It means path to log files. As Sitecore is hosted on IIS, it should be something like C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC*.log

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what is the main page for a Sitecore website. There's no index.html or index.php.

Comment: In default Sitecore instance it could be home.aspx which equals to your home item.

Comment: I see. Regarding 2): I found the log files of the IIS, but I have more than one Sitecore instance running on the IIS. How can I know which logs belong to the Sitecore instance that I want to create the reports for?